# How to set timeout in web-service call?

Tags: spring-integration

i am using

```
SimpleWebServiceOutboundGateway 
    simpleGateway.setSendTimeout(1000);
```

to call a web-service , but some time web-service takes more time to give response , and i want to set timeout so that it should terminate flow if response is delay.even after setSendTimeOut , it keeps on waiting . how can i achieve timeout ?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting JavaDocs:

```
/**
 * Set the timeout for sending reply Messages.
 * @param sendTimeout The send timeout.
 */
public void setSendTimeout(long sendTimeout) {
    this.messagingTemplate.setSendTimeout(sendTimeout);
}
```

as a part of the `AbstractMessageProducingHandler` and it is fully related to already a message to send to the output channel. That isn't a part of the SOAP protocol interaction.

You have to take a look to the options of your particular `WebServiceMessageSender`. For example `HttpComponentsMessageSender` has options like:

```
/**
 * Sets the timeout until a connection is established. A value of 0 means <em>never</em> timeout.
 *
 * @param timeout the timeout value in milliseconds
 * @see org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams#setConnectionTimeout(org.apache.http.params.HttpParams, int)
 */
public void setConnectionTimeout(int timeout) {
    if (timeout < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("timeout must be a non-negative value");
    }
    org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(getHttpClient().getParams(), timeout);
}

/**
 * Set the socket read timeout for the underlying HttpClient. A value of 0 means <em>never</em> timeout.
 *
 * @param timeout the timeout value in milliseconds
 * @see org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams#setSoTimeout(org.apache.http.params.HttpParams, int)
 */
public void setReadTimeout(int timeout) {
```

Answer (score 0):

by using configuration file,

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway request-channel="requestData"  **reply-timeout="5000"**
        supported-methods="GET" path="/{oft}/users/{userId}"
        payload-expression="#pathVariables.userId"  reply-channel="responseChannel" >
         <int-http:header name="outputfile" expression="#pathVariables.oft"/>
    </int-http:inbound-gateway>
```